# Run selenium in default browser?

Tags: c#, selenium

Is there a possibility to run selenium.chrome in the default chrome browser (the none chrome automation version). Currently, I'm having a problem where the site wants to access does not work well with the browser that selenium opens. But in my default Chrome browser, the same problem is not shown. I want to be able to open my "own" chrome browser and use selenium with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the path to the Chrome browser you want to run.

```c#
var options = new ChromeOptions()
{
    BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"
};
var driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory, options);
```